# Why am I getting a logical error in a python implemented algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, error-handling

Below is a text-based Python implementation algorithm about a task. The task is,

> "Tickets can be purchased for a single passenger or a group of passengers. When making purchase, checks that the number of tickets for the required train journeys up and down a mountain is available. If the tickets are available, calculate the total price including any group discount. Update the screen display and the data for the totals."

This is the description of this task.

> "An electric mountain railway makes four return trips every day. In each trip the train goes up the mountain at 9,11,13 and 15. The train returns from the top of the mountain at 10,12,14, and 16. Each train has 6 coaches with 80 seats. **Passenger can only buy a return tickets; all tickets must be bought on the day of travel.** The cost is $25 for the journey up and $25 for the journey down. Groups of between 10 and 80 passenger inclusive get a free ticket for every 10th passenger, provided they all travel together. Passenger must book their return train journey, as well as the departure train journey, when they buy their tickets. Passengers can return on the next trian down the mountain or a later train. **The last train from the top of the mountain has two extra coaches on it.**

> *The train times are displayed on a large screen, together with the number of tickets still available for each train. Every time a ticket is booked the display is updated. When a train is full, the word 'Closed' is displayed instead of the number of tickets available*

**When the ticket for 15 o'clock is 0 and when I try to book the ticket for 16 o'clock as there are extra tickets available it asks to enter the appropriate number of tickets rather than allowing me to book the ticket.**

***Could you please tell me why am I getting this error? Would you be able to fix the error, please? Thank you in advance!***

FYI, I'm a beginner in this field trying to learn the basic.

```
train_up_time = [9,11,13,15] 
train_down_time = [10,12,14,16]
train_up_ticket =[480]*4
train_down_ticket =[480,480,480,640]
train_up_money =[0.00]*4
train_down_money = [0.00]*4

cost = 25.00
index_up = 0
index_down = 0
ticket_cost = 0
ticket_counter = 0

print("The available time and tickets for the trip Up to the mountain ")
print("Available time\t\t Available tickets \t\t Total money of the trip / $ \n")
for i in range(0, 4):
    print(train_up_time[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_up_ticket[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_up_money[ i ])

print("The available time and tickets for the trip Down from the mountain ")
print("Available time\t\t Available tickets \t\t Total money of the trip / $ \n")
for i in range(0, 4):
    print(train_down_time[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_down_ticket[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_down_money[ i ])

selling_ticket = int(input("Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1.  :  " ))
while selling_ticket == 1:

        time_up = int(input("What time would you like to buy for 9 11 13 15? :  "))
        while time_up != 9 and time_up != 11 and time_up != 13 and time_up != 15 :
                print("Error! please select the appropraite time from the available.")
                time_up = int(input("What time would you like buy for 9 11 13 15? :  "))
                
        time_down = int(input("What time would you like to return 10 12 14 16? :  "))
        while time_up > time_down or ( time_down != 10 and time_down != 12 and time_down != 14 and time_down  != 16) :
                print("Error! please select the appropraite time (you must not select the time below the departure)." )
                time_down = int(input("What time would you like to return 10 12 14 16? :  "))
                
        for count in range(0,4):
                if time_up == train_up_time[ count ]:
                        index_up = count
                if time_down == train_down_time[ count]:
                        index_down = count

        for i in range(0, 4):
                if train_up_ticket [ index_up ] ==  "CLOSED":
                        train_up_ticket [ index_up ] = 0
                if train_down_ticket[ index_down ] == "CLOSED" :
                        train_down_ticket[ index_down ] = 0


        num_ticket = int(input("How many tickets would you like to buy? :  "))
        while  num_ticket > train_up_ticket[ index_up ] or num_ticket > train_down_ticket [ index_down ] :
                        print("Error! Please recheck the availability of the trian ticket")
                        num_ticket = int(input("How many tickets would you like to buy? :  "))
                        
        print("Every 10th passenger is FREE!")
        train_up_ticket [ index_up ] = train_up_ticket [ index_up ] -  num_ticket
        train_down_ticket[ index_down ] = train_down_ticket[ index_down ] - num_ticket
        if num_ticket >= 10:
                ticket_cost = cost * (num_ticket - (num_ticket/10))
        else:
                ticket_cost = cost * num_ticket
        print("Your trip cost:  ", "$", ticket_cost)
        print("You need to pay for both ways")
        print("Therefore, your total trip cost including the discount is :   ", "$", ticket_cost*2 )

        train_up_money[ index_up ] = train_up_money[ index_up ] +  ticket_cost
        train_down_money[ index_down ] = train_down_money[ index_down ] + ticket_cost
        if train_up_ticket [ index_up ] ==  0:
                train_up_ticket [ index_up ] = "CLOSED"
        if train_down_ticket[ index_down ] == 0:
                train_down_ticket[ index_down ] = "CLOSED"        
                
        print("The available time and tickets for the trip Up to the mountain ")
        print("Available time\t\t Available tickets \t\t Total money of the trip / $ \n")
        for i in range(0, 4):
                print(train_up_time[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_up_ticket[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_up_money[ i ])
        print("The available time and tickets for the trip Down from the mountain ")
        print("Available time\t\t Available tickets \t\t Total money of the trip / $ \n")
        for i in range(0, 4):
                print(train_down_time[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_down_ticket[ i ], "\t\t\t", train_down_money[ i ])

        selling_ticket = int(input("Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1.  :  " ))
```

Comment: Use the breakpoint() call. Much faster that way.

Comment: Add the specific set of inputs that triggers this error

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem here:

```
while  num_ticket > train_up_ticket[ index_down ] or num_ticket > train_down_ticket [ index_down ] :
```

I think it should be `index_up` for the first comparison.

Comment: Thank you mhawke but yet I'm not getting the expected result

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me out

Comment: Your code is checking that there are sufficient tickets available for _both_ up and down journeys. That seems consistent with your requirements. So, if there are not enough tickets for either journey then you can not proceed to book any tickets. It looks right to me. What is your expected result?

Comment: actually, in the main description it mentioned that tickets can still buy for 16 o'clock for 160 passengers, so when I try to book ticket for 16 o'clock an error is produced that asks to enter the appropriate number.

Comment: "When making purchase, checks that the number of tickets for the required train journeys up and down a mountain is available." There's no mention of it being possible to buy tickets for only the down journey. Update your question with these additional requirements.

Comment: I think that the extra 160 tickets are because there would likely be more people wanting to return on the last train.

Comment: I have updated the whole question. I would be very grateful to you if could do something to improve my algorithm. It has been a month I am working on this. Thank you so much for your interest.

Comment: @HarveyHarris: I'm sorry, but I don't see how anything has changed with the updated spec. If there are not enough tickets available for the up journey for the requested time, then you can not get buy a ticket at that time. Since all purchases must include a return journey you can't buy a ticket.

Comment: @HarveyHarris: You could improve things if you were to check ticket availability when the user enters the time for the up journey, and prevent them proceeding until they have entered a time for which sufficient tickets exist. So, ask for the number of tickets up front, then check whether there are any up-down train combinations that have enough available seats. Then present only the available train times for the up trip, then display the available train times for the return trip.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any logical issue in the code. Here is the sample log from your program:

```
Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1: 1
What time would you like to buy for 9 11 13 15?: 15
What time would you like to return 10 12 14 16?: 16
How many tickets would you like to buy?: 480
Every 10th passenger is FREE!
Your trip cost:   $ 10800.0
You need to pay for both ways
Therefore, your total trip cost including the discount is :    $ 21600.0
The available time and tickets for the trip Up to the mountain 
Available time       Available tickets       Total money of the trip / $ 

9                480                 0.0
11               480                 0.0
13               480                 0.0
15               CLOSED                  10800.0
The available time and tickets for the trip Down from the mountain 
Available time       Available tickets       Total money of the trip / $ 

10               480                 0.0
12               480                 0.0
14               480                 0.0
16               160                 10800.0


Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1: 1
What time would you like to buy for 9 11 13 15?: 9
What time would you like to return 10 12 14 16?: 16
How many tickets would you like to buy?: 160
Every 10th passenger is FREE!
Your trip cost:   $ 3600.0
You need to pay for both ways
Therefore, your total trip cost including the discount is :    $ 7200.0
The available time and tickets for the trip Up to the mountain 
Available time       Available tickets       Total money of the trip / $ 

9                320                 3600.0
11               480                 0.0
13               480                 0.0
15               CLOSED                  10800.0
The available time and tickets for the trip Down from the mountain 
Available time       Available tickets       Total money of the trip / $ 

10               480                 0.0
12               480                 0.0
14               480                 0.0
16               CLOSED                  14400.0


Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1: 1
What time would you like to buy for 9 11 13 15?: 9
What time would you like to return 10 12 14 16?: 14
How many tickets would you like to buy?: 320
Every 10th passenger is FREE!
Your trip cost:   $ 7200.0
You need to pay for both ways
Therefore, your total trip cost including the discount is :    $ 14400.0
The available time and tickets for the trip Up to the mountain 
Available time       Available tickets       Total money of the trip / $ 

9                CLOSED                  10800.0
11               480                 0.0
13               480                 0.0
15               CLOSED                  10800.0
The available time and tickets for the trip Down from the mountain 
Available time       Available tickets       Total money of the trip / $ 

10               480                 0.0
12               480                 0.0
14               160                 7200.0
16               CLOSED                  14400.0


Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1:
```

I fix some line indentation and you can check my code:

```
train_up_time = [9,11,13,15] 
train_down_time = [10,12,14,16]
train_up_ticket =[480]*4
train_down_ticket =[480,480,480,640]
train_up_money =[0.00]*4
train_down_money = [0.00]*4

cost = 25.00
index_up = 0
index_down = 0
ticket_cost = 0
ticket_counter = 0
selling_ticket = int(input("Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1: "))
while selling_ticket == 1:
    time_up = int(input("What time would you like to buy for 9 11 13 15?: "))
    while time_up != 9 and time_up != 11 and time_up != 13 and time_up != 15 :
        print("Error! please select the appropraite time from the available.")
        time_up = int(input("What time would you like buy for 9 11 13 15?: "))
            
    time_down = int(input("What time would you like to return 10 12 14 16?: "))
    while time_up > time_down or ( time_down != 10 and time_down != 12 and time_down != 14 and time_down  != 16) :
        print("Error! please select the appropraite time (you must not select the time below the departure)." )
        time_down = int(input("What time would you like to return 10 12 14 16?: "))
            
    for count in range(0,4):
        if time_up == train_up_time[ count ]:
            index_up = count
        if time_down == train_down_time[ count]:
            index_down = count

    for i in range(0, 4):
        if train_up_ticket [ index_up ] ==  "CLOSED":
            train_up_ticket [ index_up ] = 0

        if train_down_ticket[ index_down ] == "CLOSED" :
            train_down_ticket[ index_down ] = 0

    # print("time_up: {}, time_down: {}".format(time_up, time_down))
    # print("index_up: {}, index_down: {}".format(index_up, index_down))
    # print("train_up_ticket: {}, train_down_ticket: {}".format(train_up_ticket, train_down_ticket))
    
    num_ticket = int(input("How many tickets would you like to buy?: "))
    while  num_ticket > train_up_ticket[ index_up ] or num_ticket > train_down_ticket[ index_down ]:
        print("Error! Please recheck the availability of the trian ticket")
        num_ticket = int(input("How many tickets would you like to buy?: "))
                    
    print("Every 10th passenger is FREE!")
    train_up_ticket[ index_up ] = train_up_ticket[ index_up ] - num_ticket
    train_down_ticket[ index_down ] = train_down_ticket[ index_down ] - num_ticket
    
    # print("train_up_ticket: {}, train_down_ticket: {}".format(train_up_ticket, train_down_ticket))
    
    if num_ticket >= 10:
        ticket_cost = cost * (num_ticket - (num_ticket/10))
    else:
        ticket_cost = cost * num_ticket
        
    print("Your trip cost:  ", "$", ticket_cost)
    print("You need to pay for both ways")
    print("Therefore, your total trip cost including the discount is :   ", "$", ticket_cost*2 )

    train_up_money[ index_up ] = train_up_money[ index_up ] +  ticket_cost
    train_down_money[ index_down ] = train_down_money[ index_down ] + ticket_cost
    
    if train_up_ticket [ index_up ] ==  0:
        train_up_ticket [ index_up ] = "CLOSED"
        
    if train_down_ticket[ index_down ] == 0:
        train_down_ticket[ index_down ] = "CLOSED"        
            
    print("The available time and tickets for the trip Up to the mountain ")
    print("Available time\t\t Available tickets \t\t Total money of the trip / $ \n")
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(train_up_time[ i ], "\t\t\t\t", train_up_ticket[ i ], "\t\t\t\t", train_up_money[ i ])
        
    print("The available time and tickets for the trip Down from the mountain ")
    print("Available time\t\t Available tickets \t\t Total money of the trip / $ \n")
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(train_down_time[ i ], "\t\t\t\t", train_down_ticket[ i ], "\t\t\t\t", train_down_money[i])

    # print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n")
    selling_ticket = int(input("Would you like buy ticket for trip ? Enter 1 else -1: "))
```